# Using jquery to get value of text area in closest table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table

```
<tr>
<td data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not Started"><img  src="images/small_info_icon.png"></td>
<td>Demo Demo</td>
<td>January</td>
<td class="updaterow"><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="notes34455" name="editcomments">Not Started</textarea></td>
<td id="34455"><button type="button" id="updatestatus" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Update</button> </td>
</tr>
```

I want to use jquery to get the value of the textarea.
I am using the following, but it is giving undefined.

```
$("button#updatestatus").click(function(){
var id = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
var data = $(this).closest("updaterow").text;     
alert(data); 
var data = {
            id: id,

            };
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "updatestatus.php",
data: data
}).done(function(msg) {
console.log(msg);           
});
```

Is it possible to get the textvalue of the textarea?

Comment: It's `.text()`.

Comment: Missing a `.` in `.closest("updaterow")`. It wouldn't work anyway as that element isn't an ancestor.

Comment: Why are you using `.closest()` for `.updaterow`? `.closest()` looks for containing parents that match, but `.updaterow` doesn't contain the button.

Comment: try `var data = $(this).closest("tr").find('.updaterow').text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

```
$("button#updatestatus").click(function(){

var data = $(this).parent().prev("td.updaterow").find("textarea").val();     
alert(data); 

});
```

Here is an example

```js
$("button#updatestatus").click(function(){

var data = $(this).parent().prev("td.updaterow").find("textarea").val();     
alert(data); 
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>


<table>
<tr>
<td data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not Started"><img  src="images/small_info_icon.png"></td>
<td>Demo Demo</td>
<td>January</td>
<td class="updaterow"><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="notes34455" name="editcomments">Not Started</textarea></td>
<td id="34455"><button type="button" id="updatestatus" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Update</button> </td>
</tr>

</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` looks for the closest containing element that matches the selector. `.updaterow` doesn't contain `button#updatestatus`, so it won't find it. `.updaterow` is the previous `td`, so it should be:

```
var data = $(this).closest("tr").siblings(".updaterow").text();
```

You also forgot the `.` in `.updaterow` and the `()` in `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need -

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').val();
```

Here is a fiddle for the same - https://jsfiddle.net/v44rzxLo/1/. On a side note, do not have same ids for multiple elements.